# How to get the created numpy arrays from keras generator?

Tags: keras

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(directory)
```

How to get the created data and label numpy arrays from generator.

I have tried `generator.__getitem__` but could not get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset_as_tuple = next(generator)
```

will give you a tuple of (x, y), where x is an array of the inputs (typically the images) and y an array of the labels. By using `next()`, you with get `batch_size` samples. Set

```
generator.batch_size  = generator.samples
```

if you want number of samples to be the number of samples in the generator.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot, I think there is no way to retrieve the numpy arrays from the ImageDataGenerator unless you change the source code